# Use proxy in webBrowser without editing registry

Tags: c#, proxy, browser

I would like to use a proxy in my webbrowser but without editing the registry on the machine.

Comment: i need to change the proxies on the go with the webbrowser control in C#. Not simply IE.

Comment: The C# WebBrowser is just the IE ActiveX control wrapped in a .net control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that would still adjust the system settings.  If you want to adjust only the proxy settings for your own process, you can do that via [UrlMkSetSessionOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exposed by urlmon.dll.  An example of this function is listed below.  For more information on INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328(v=vs.85).aspx.

```
private void SetSessionProxy(strin ProxyAddress, string BypassList)
{
    var proxyInfo= new INTERNET_PROXY_INFO {
        dwAccessType = 0x3,
        lpszProxy = ProxyAddress,
        lpszProxyBypass = BypassList
    };
    int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(proxyInfo);
    const uint SetProxy = 0x26;

    if (Win32Native.UrlMkSetSessionOption(SetProxy, structure, dwLen, 0) != 0)
        throw new Win32Exception();
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private class INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
{
    public uint dwAccessType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string lpszProxy;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string lpszProxyBypass;
}

[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(uint dwOption, INTERNET_PROXY_INFO structNewProxy, uint dwLen, uint dwZero);
```